# Is there an equivalent for GDownloadUrl function in Google Maps API v3

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, xmlhttprequest

I used the Google Maps API version 2 function [`GDownloadUrl`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GDownloadUrl) on various places to download XML/JSON data. I am converting about 3 dozen map pages to version 3 and I am unable to find an equivalent of this function. Is there one or should I use another library for handling AJAX/XHR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built in function in the google maps API v3 (there are [several discussions in the v3 group](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/search?hl=en&group=google-maps-js-api-v3&q=GDownloadUrl&qt_g=Search+this+group) if you want some history, including [this one including an answer by Pamela Fox from google (at the time)](https://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-js-api-v3/browse_frm/thread/12542ae618555594/660c2a04d67cc1dd?hl=en&lnk=gst&q=GDownloadUrl#660c2a04d67cc1dd)).  There is an example in the [demo gallery](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery) (search for xml), and I have a version that I use in this [example from Mike WIlliams' v2 tutorial that I translated to v3](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent function in the API V3. I use [this separate function](http://maps.forum.nu/ajax2.js) that I wrote based on this example:

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/AJAX:Getting_Started#Step_3_.E2.80.93_A_Simple_Example

(It works fine in all browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of...

```
    GDownloadUrl('https://your/url.json', function(data) {
        // ...
    });
```

...you can do this, assuming you have [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) loaded and is available as `$`:

```
    $.get('https://your/url.json', function(data) {
        // ...
    });
```