# GMap V3 valid JSON from PHP as replacement for GDownloadUrl

Tags: google-maps-api-3

In V2 Gmap Api I am able to use to GDownloadUrl to read JSON values generated in my php and process the value and show them on the map well. I need to do the same in V3 and GDownloadUrl is not there and what is the best way to achieve this now?

Comment: You might want to check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11539630/is-there-an-equivalet-for-gdownloadurl-function-in-google-maps-api-v3

Comment: @niaccurshi I saw the link there mostly are talking about generating XML file and reading so there is now way I can read for e.g. in my php I generate it using this method "array_push($data1, array( ... " . So what is the best mechanism to read those values?

Comment: I may be wrong, but if your code works, my understanding would be that you need to simply replace your GDownloadUrl function with a Jquery "get" function. Without seeing the code I can't be sure, but in theory all the v2 function did was download data in an easy command from an external file. That's exactly what many javascript libraries do now by thmselves. :)

Comment: Other possible duplicates [here](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[google-maps-api-3]+GDownloadUrl)